# How can i create a stage in java FX which forces user to first close it for doing anything else?

Tags: javafx

I am creating a desktop app using java fx and here I want to prevent the user from accessing the PC unless my app is closed.
I tried using showAndWait() function but it is not applicable to primary stage.
Its a single page app.
Help will be appreciated. Thanks!
Here is my main class and i am using scene builder for designing.

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        TilePane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Layout.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.showAndWait();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you could block other parts of your computer with pure Java. That would require a lot more work either way. You can force the user to close the window before interacting with the rest of Java application quite easily, though.

Comment: "_...prevent the user from accessing the PC unless my app is closed_". I've never encountered an application (at least on Windows) that _legitimately_ stops the user from interacting with the rest of the computer. Are you sure Windows (or whatever OS you're on) even supports what you want to do? I'd be surprised if such a feature existed (but maybe it does).

Comment: I am creating a log in application so i want that user cant access the computer without logging in. I want to achieve the effect of a popup but using a single window such that user cant simply turn off my application and start using the computer

Comment: Does it help to set 'always on top' in combination with a `WindowFocusListener` which request focus upon losing it? (Can still be closed with taskManager, but it is an attempt at least).

Comment: This sounds like something that would be highly platform-dependent and, if it's possible, would require native code.